# Raspbian Desktop Audio Not Working

Tags: raspbian, audio

I have checked many forums and Google, and I cannot find it anywhere.
I have just installed Raspbian desktop on my laptop (acer aspire v5-123) and when I boot into the Raspbian Stretch the audio does not work, I cannot turn the volume up either.

Is there a fix to this?

Comment: You might be better asking on the Raspberry Pi forum section 'Raspberry Pi Desktop for PC and Mac' https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewforum.php?f=116

Comment: Questions about RPi Desktop are [off-topic](https://raspberrypi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2121/raspberry-pi-desktop-for-pc-mac), sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Right click on the audio symbol in the top right corner of the taskbar, and select your audio device. I think RPD has issues identifying the correct default one. You should see something like Realtek Audio and HDMI Audio. Try the first one, which should be your laptop's built-in speakers.